# Set where the speed of convergence is uniform in Lebesgue's density theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $B \subset \mathbb R^n$ be the unit ball.
Consider a Borel measurable set $E \subset B$ with positive Lebesgue measure $|E|>0$ (say $|E| = |B|/2$).

Then, Lebesgue's density theorem, says that for a.e. $x\in E$
$$
\lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{|B(x,r)\backslash E|}{|B(x,r)|} = 0.
$$

We can restate it as follows: for a.e. $x\in E$, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $r_0 = r_0(x, \epsilon)>0$ such that
$$
|B(x,r)\backslash E| \leq \epsilon |B(x,r)|, \quad 0<r<r_0(x,\epsilon) .
$$
I am particularly interested in the dependence $\epsilon(r, x)$.

I have a question about this. Probably it has been studied but I have not been able to find any reference.

Given $E$, can we prove some uniformity for $\epsilon$ in a positive measure set (maybe of measure smaller than $|E|$)? That is, can we find some $r_*>0$ and $\phi$ continuous with $\phi(0)=0$ such that
$$
\epsilon(r,x) \leq \phi(r), \quad 0<r<r_*
$$
for all $x \in \tilde E$ for some Borel set $\tilde E\subset E$ with $0<|\tilde E|\leq |E|$.

**Edit:**
Initially I had two questions but I have decided to delete one.

Comment: Did you see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405361/bounds-of-speed-of-convergence-in-lebesgues-density-theorem?

Comment: Ad 1: The good news is that you have $|B_r \ E | \le |B_s \ E| \le |B_r \ E| + |B_s \ B_r |$ for $r<s$, which is optimal. If you play around this, you should get some estimates on the local Lipschitz constant of $\epsilon(r)$. The bad news is that the estimate will be something like $Lip(\epsilon) \approx 1/r$. So as long as you start early enough you can grow as fast as you want. Ad 2: I think for any fixed $r$, I can find $E$ such that $\epsilon(r) > 1/10$ or so, by a variation of the usual dense union of balls counterexample. There still might be some room if you are $E$-dependent though.

Comment: @BorisBukh That link is recursive...

Comment: Sorry. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242919/speed-of-convergence-in-lebesgues-density-theorem

Comment: @BorisBukh I don't think the other question is entirely related to mine

Comment: I am thinking about question 1 in dimension 1 in the case E is some Smith-Volterra-Cantor set.

Comment: Tao writes about this (in dimension 1) here: https://www.google.com.my/amp/s/terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/06/18/the-lebesgue-differentiation-theorem-and-the-szemeredi-regularity-lemma/amp/. Maybe you might find something of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$f_n(x) = \sup_{r \in {\mathbb Q} \cap [\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})} \frac{|B(x,r)\setminus  E|}{|B(x,r)|}\,,$$ so that $f_n(x) \to 0$ for a.e. $x \in E$. By Egorov's theorem [1], for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a subset
$\tilde{E} \subset E$ with $|E \setminus \tilde{E}| <\epsilon$, such that
$f_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly on $\tilde{E}$. It follows that
$$
\lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{|B(x,r)\backslash E|}{|B(x,r)|} = 0
$$
uniformly in $\tilde{E}$, even when the limit is considered for real $r>0$.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem